# Add array inside of object Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, object, typescript

I'm trying to create new objects with arrays inside of them but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is what my service looks like:

```
export class Hero {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public type: string,
    public photos: string[]
    ) { }
}

let HEROES = [
  new Hero(
    11,
    'Mr. Nice',
    'Fire',
    ('link to a photo', 'link to another photo')
  ),
  new Hero(
    12,
    'Narco',
    'Earth',
    ('link to a photo', 'link to another photo', 'another one')
  )
];
```

Basically, I have a constructor to define what the Hero object should look like. The things that's not working is the photos: string[]. I'd like to be able to have an array of photos to show, some 'heroes' will have photos, some won't so the amount is not determined. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are initialized with square brackets.

```
let HEROES = [
  new Hero(
    11,
    'Mr. Nice',
    'Fire',
    ['link to a photo', 'link to another photo']
  ),
  new Hero(
    12,
    'Narco',
    'Earth',
    ['link to a photo', 'link to another photo', 'another one']
  )
];
```

Comment: Yes, sorry! Forgot to change the name of this one. I tried using this [ ] instead of the parenthesis, but I still get this error though: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Can you update the question with that info @L.G. ? I'd like to see the  exact code and line number. I'm not getting any errors once I take what you've got there and update it to use square brackets.

Comment: So sorry, I had defined something else in the constructor before the photos: string[], which is why it showed an error. uhh, such a clutz! thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Define the array in the constructor like this:

`public photos: Array<string>`